# How to capture output in a variable rather than a logfile?

Tags: powershell, console, output-redirect

This would write the output to a logfile:

```
& $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe >test.log
```

But what if I wanted to keep the output in a string variable to use it in the email body?

I tried this without any luck..

```
$test = ""
& $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe >$test

Write-Host $test
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to do:

```
$test = & $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe
```

If you wanted to redirect error as well, add `2>&1` in the end.

Comment: One more thing, could $test be an array or list instead? It would be great to add to a collection when executing a command and at the end I just could loop through the collection and add them to email body?

Comment: I think you can cast it to an array: [string[]] $test = & $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe

Answer (score 27):

Capturing the output of a executable is as simple as,

```
$cmdOutput = &"Application.exe" 2>&1
```

> 2>&1 - Includes the error stream in the output

Return type of the executable in PowerShell is an **array of strings**. In case of logging such outputs,

```
Write-Host $cmdOutput
```

will output the strings in the array to the output stream separated by spaces

To print them in a string per line fashion, choose

```
Write-Output $cmdOutput
```

or

```
$cmdOutput = &"Application.exe" | Out-String
Write-Host $cmdOutput
```

Comment: The case where I needed Out-String is for multiline output to go to one big string.

Comment: ```$hash = git log -1  --pretty=format:"%h" --no-patch | Out-String```
2nd example

Answer (score 1):

If you are using powershell >= 5.0

The `Tee-Object` command supports both variables and files. [Reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object).

```
& $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe | Tee-Object -Variable test
```

`Tee-Object` forwards any input further down the pipe, so if you also want to prevent output to console/host you will need to redirect to `Out-Null`

```
& $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe | Tee-Object -Variable test | Out-Null
```